# Shiny App: eventReactive and reactive inconsistent behaviour with actionButton to "Refresh"

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to understand why I get different behaviors than I expect when using `eventReactive` instead of `reactive` together with an `actionButton` to refresh the page.

For example, this simple Shiny dashboard behaves as I expect: upon loading the plot is displayed and I can modify the filter and refresh the plot when clicking on the refresh button.

```
# app1.R

library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

species <- levels(iris$Species)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("species", "Select Iris Species", 
          choices = species, selected=species, multiple = TRUE),
      actionButton("refresh", "Refresh")
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("scatterplot"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  selected_data <- reactive({
    input$refresh
    isolate({
    iris %>% filter(Species %in% input$species)
  })
  })

  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    plot(selected_data())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Based on my understanding of `actionButton` and `eventReactive` I though I could replace the code for `selected_data` with

```
selected_data <- eventReactive( input$refresh, {
  iris %>% filter(Species %in% input$species)
})
```

this way I make explicit that `selected_data` only depends on `input$refresh`.

However the app doesn't behave as I expect: upon loading no plot is shown and I have to explicitely click on "Refresh" to get the plot displayed. After that everything works as intended.

Here is the full code for the second version of the app:

```
# app2.R

library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

species <- levels(iris$Species)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("species", "Select Iris Species", 
          choices = species, selected=species, multiple = TRUE),
      actionButton("refresh", "Refresh")
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("scatterplot"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  selected_data <- eventReactive( input$refresh, {

    iris %>% filter(Species %in% input$species)

  })

  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    plot(selected_data())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

According to the documentation, when the Shiny app is executed `input$refresh` should have changed value from NULL to 0, which in turns triggers the evaluation of `selected_data` and showing the plot.

Can you explain me why in `app1.R` the plot is shown when the app is loaded and in `app2.R` you have to force the refresh manually?

Is there any (clean) way I can make `app2.R` show the plot when the app is loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an argument within `eventReactive` which is `ignoreNULL` and it is set to `TRUE` by default, if you change that to `FALSE` it will trigger. For more info please refer to `?eventReactive`

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

species <- levels(iris$Species)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("species", "Select Iris Species", 
                  choices = species, selected=species, multiple = TRUE),
      actionButton("refresh", "Refresh")
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("scatterplot"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  selected_data <- eventReactive( input$refresh, {
    iris %>% filter(Species %in% input$species)
  },ignoreNULL = F)

  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    plot(selected_data())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```